# Client-side validation THEN pass to server OR disable submit until form complete - How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

```
export default function RegistrationForm() {

    useEffect(() => {
        const getAPI = () => {
            const API = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
            fetch(API)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    setLoading(false);
                    setApiData(data);
                });
        };
        getAPI();
    }, []);
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    function verifyPassword() {
        let pass1 = document.getElementById("password").value;
        let pass2 = document.getElementById("confPass").value;
        let match = true;

        if (pass1 != pass2) {
            alert("Passwords Do not match");
            document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
            document.getElementById("confPass").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
            match = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#07b800";
            document.getElementById("confPass").style.borderColor = "#07b800";
        }
        return match;
    }
    return (
        <div className="form-container">
            <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000/add-user">
                <input type="text"
                       name="firstName"
                       placeholder="First Name"
                       value="James"
                       id="firstName"
                       required
                />
                <input type="text"
                       name="lastName"
                       placeholder="Last Name"
                       value="James"
                       id="lastName"
                       required
                />
                <input type="email"
                       name="emailAdd"
                       placeholder="Email Address"
                       value="jim@jim.com"
                       id="emailAdd"
                       required
                />
                <select type="text"
                        name="gender"
                        list="genderDropdown"
                        id="gender"
                        required>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
                <input type="date"
                       name="dob"
                       placeholder="D.O.B"
                       id="dob"
                       required
                />
                <input type="password"
                       name="password"
                       placeholder="Password"
                       id="password"
                       required
                />
                <input type="password"
                       name="confirmPassword"
                       id="confPass"
                       placeholder="Confirm Password"
                       required
                />
                <input type="submit" value="COMPLETE REGISTRATION"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

At the moment, this code will immediately send the data to my Postgres database. However I would like the passwords to match before it gets there - the verifyPassword() method does this, but doesn't work with the code as it currently stands. *It's not being called in the above code, but doesn't work when it is called, UNLESS the method/action part is removed.

I can

1. only verify the password OR
2. I can send to the DB.

It won't let me do one without the other. How can I sort this?

Comment: "*doesn't work when it is called*" - please show us *how* you were going to call it

Comment: Please don't make destructive edits to questions, even if they are your own. Especially when they have accepted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `form` is an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in React.
What you need to do first, is take control of all your form's inputs and `onSubmit` method.
So you can handle the password verification and call the API when needed.

Once, you've stored all input values in state.
Then your code for disabling form input and form's `onFormSubmit` method would look something like this -

Disabled Input

```
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true)

<input type="submit" value="COMPLETE REGISTRATION" disabled={isDisabled}/>
```

Form Submit

```
const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
  // we do this to prevent browser's default form submit behaviour
  e.preventDefault();

  if(verifyPassword()) {
    setIsDisabledInput(false)
    // fetch POST function call
  } else {
   setIsDisabledInput(true)
 }
}

<form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
```